# Accessing elements in a vector of tuples C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following body of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> edges(4,{1,2});

    for (auto i = std::begin (edges); i != std::end (edges); ++i) {
            std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << " "<< std::get<1>(i)<< " ";
        }
}
```

In my eyes this makes sense, I have a vector of tuples which I'm initialising. I then iterate through the vector printing each of the two elements of the tuple individually.

However the code [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/Krb3s9GTd) returning

```
8:26: error: no matching function for call to 'get'
   std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << " "<< std::get<1>(i)<< " ";
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: `i` is an iterator over tuples; `*i` is a tuple.

Comment: What does your tuple represent, I often find that creating a struct of my own with clear names makes code much more readable. I also would replace the for loop with a range based for loop and iterate over const & of the vector. like : for(const auto& edge : edges) std::cout << edge.from << ", " << edge.to << "\n". Or something along those lines

Comment: offtopic: tuples are designed to be used in templates. In regular code it is a better practice to use struct with properly named fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change to a range-based `for` loop

```
for (auto const& edge : edges) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(edge) << " "<< std::get<1>(edge)<< " ";
}
```

Otherwise to access each edge, you need to dereference your iterator using `*` to get the actual tuple itself

```
for (auto iter = std::begin(edges); iter != std::end(edges); ++iter) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*iter) << " "<< std::get<1>(*iter)<< " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i` is not a `std::tuple<int, int>`, it is a pointer (iterator) to one (`std::tuple<int, int>*`); you need to dereference it.

---

If you are able to step to C++17 you could use structured bindings in a range-based for loop instead:

```
for (auto [a, b] : edges) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error message can be intimidating. Sometimes you need to dig a bit to find the relevant parts. For your code, when [compiled with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/cq8orGffe), this part of the error message is a good hint:

```
In file included from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211209/include/c++/12.0.0/tuple:1380:5: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> constexpr std::__tuple_element_t<__i, std::tuple<_UTypes ...> >& std::get(tuple<_UTypes ...>&)'
 1380 |     get(tuple<_Elements...>& __t) noexcept
      |     ^~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211209/include/c++/12.0.0/tuple:1380:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:8:37: note:   '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tuple<int, int>*, std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > >' is not derived from 'std::tuple<_UTypes ...>'
    8 |             std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << " "<< std::get<1>(i)<< " ";
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

The compilers internal names being used in the message don't make it easier, though what the message tries to tell is that there is some `get` that takes a tuple as parameter and returns its element (`constexpr std::__tuple_element_t<__i, std::tuple<_UTypes ...> >& std::get(tuple<_UTypes ...>&)`), but what you pass is an iterator from a vector of tuples (`__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tuple<int, int>*, std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > >'`). They don't match. You need to dereference the iterator to get a reference to the tuple.